# Does the centrifugal force varies according to distance of the observer (in a rotating frame of reference ) from the centre of rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

Imagine yourself in empty space. No stars. Nothing.

You (Observer) are fixed on an invisible rotating disc (with angular velocity $w$) at a radius $r$ from the centre of rotation and you are observing a box at distance $S (S>r)$, stationary w.r.t to the centre of the disc.

What will be the centrifugal force on the box w.r.t to the observer? I think the box will appear to move somewhat elliptical or back and forth.

Does the centrifugal force on the box depend upon the distance of the observer from the box? How will it appear to move?

Edit :I asked how does centrifugal force depends on the position of The observer in a rotating frame of reference. But some super smart closed this question . If you can’t answer let it be answered by someone else.

Comment: No it doesn’t .those are completely different